# Why do I get a timeout although webelement is visible selenium?

Tags: selenium

In selenium I have the following code

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Create new collab']")))
```

in order to select an input field inside the following construct:

```
<div class="md-input-container md-theme-default md-input-placeholder">
  <label>Collab Name</label> 
  <input placeholder="Create new collab" class="md-input" type="text">     
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  ::after
</div>
```

But I get a timeout exception after a wait for 10 seconds. Manually I am able to click and type something in that input field a second after is is being loaded.

The following `ExpectedConditions` are unable to find the element:

- `visibility_of_element_located`
- `element_to_be_clickable`

while this methid is able to find the element:

- `presence_of_element_located`

but I am not able to use `send_keys` to the input field. I get an `ElementNotInteractableException` error. Also 'clicking' in the element before does not work - same error.

So what to try else?

Comment: Try using element_to_be_visible or element_to_be_present.  Maybe for some reason the input is not clickable.

Comment: Any chance this input text element is inside an iframe or frame?

Comment: @Grasshopper: It is, but I selected that frame before and executed some other successfull actions in this frame

Comment: @smit9234: You mean `visibility_of_element_located`?

Comment: Can you do the screenshot and check if the element looks enabled and fit into the browsers viewport?

Comment: The origin of your timeout is not clear. It could be the from the waiter, the server or the page. Please add a stack-trace, or at least the exception's signature.

Comment: @Alex sorry, just saw this was Python, so try presence_of_element_located, visibility_of, visibility_of_element_located

Comment: Open up this page in Chrome and open the devtools. Use `$x(//input[@placeholder='Create new collab'])` to test your XPath and see how many elements are returned. My guess is there's more than one on the page and the first one is hidden.

Comment: @smit9234 It seems that `presence_of_element_located` works. What the heck is the differences between those methods anyway? I saw the documentation, but if an element is 'clickable', 'present', 'visible' is of no interest to me. Just find an element and USE it!

Comment: @smit9234: Nope, its not longer working. I worked for an hour, but now I am not able to use `send_keys` to fill that input field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The div with `class - 'md-tabs-wrapper'` has a `style attribute - 'transform: translate3d(-748px, 0px, 0px);'`. This div contains the input box that you are trying to interact. What the `transform:translate3d` does it is shift the divs and contents to the left and **outside the viewport of the browser**. You can test it by copying the relevant div in browser and then switching off this style or changing the values.

This kind off explains why the `"presence" EC` **works** but visibility and click EC do not. Apparently selenium is not able to figure that element is visible and thus throws the `ElementNotInteractableException`.

Use ActionChains instead. Use the element from the presence EC.

```
actions = ActionChains(driver) 
actions.move_to_element(element) 
actions.send_keys("hello world") 
actions.perform()
```

Also need to clear the existing placeholder text for the sendkeys to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@class='md-input' and @type='text']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem) 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
my_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='md-input' and @type='text']")))
my_element.click()
```